# Have friendly_id slugs only applied if condition x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rubygems, friendly-id

I have friendly_id applied and working but now I dont want it to add a slug if the `key_type` is `4`

currently I have

```
 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :value, :use => :scoped, :scope => [:category_item_key, :category_item]
```

and tired applying an if statement in the model like below

```
  if :key_type == 4
  else
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :value, :use => :scoped, :scope => [:category_item_key, :category_item]
  end
```

But the if statement doesn't seem to do anything. I figured there might be a built in way in friendly_id for this to be done (couldn't see anything in the docs). Or maybe thee is some other way of getting this done so it wont add a slug if the `key_type` is equal to `4`?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
before_create :add_slug_if_needed

def add_slug_if_needed
  self.slug = 'hey_look_a_slug' unless key_type == 4
end
```

I'm suggesting this instead of a `FriendlyId` approach because conditionally extending modules seems like a can of worms!